# Lower torque spec for a used rear strut-to-axel carrier nut versus new?

Tags: struts

I am replacing struts on my 2004 Toyota Camry LE (4 cyl).  The rear suspension strut-to-axle carrier nuts/bolts (19mm) have a torque spec of 188 ft. lbs. in an official 2004 Camry Repair online manual.

I also have a Haynes Repair Manual for the same car. It specifies the following:

New nut: 188 ft. lbs.
Used nut: 145 ft. lbs.

Why would it specify a lower spec for a used nut?  It doesn't make the same distinction when specifying the torque for the same, but larger (22mm) bolts/nuts on the front suspension.  For the front, it simply says 155 ft. lbs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the new nut has a “self locking” design which needs extra torque to deliver the same force to the fixing, while the old nut does not have that any more.

Comment: I wrote the publisher of the Haynes manual, not expecting a quick reply, and to my surprise a technician answered right away.  The 2001 factory service manual does specify a different used nut torque, apparently for the reason you give.  But 2002-2005 (the models my manual covers) does not have this distinction.  Therefore, it is a misprint in the Haynes manual.

Comment: Well done and best of luck with finishing the work.